# Proving a limit of a function using the definition

Tags: real-analysis, limits

If g and h are defined in a neighborhood of c and $\lim_{x\to c} g(x)$ = $\lim_{x\to c} h(x)$ = L, and we define f by

$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
h(x),  & \text{if $x$ ∈ Q } \\
g(x), & \text{if $x$ ∉ Q}
\end{cases}$

Show that $\lim_{x\to c} f(x)$ = L.

I know that I should be using the definition of a limit here but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Take the minimum of the $\delta$s and use the density of $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: I don't mean to sound rude at all but could you elaborate a little more? I'm not sure how to use the density of Q. Thanks for the fast response though!

Answer (score 0):

Let $\varepsilon > 0$, then because the limit exists for $g$ and $h$, we have a $\delta_{g, \varepsilon}$ such that if $$|x-c| < \delta_{g, \varepsilon} \quad\Rightarrow\quad |g(x) - L| < \varepsilon$$
And a $\delta_{h,\varepsilon}$ such that if $$|x-c| < \delta_{h,\varepsilon} \quad \Rightarrow \quad|h(x) - L| < \varepsilon$$

Now take $\delta_{\varepsilon} = min \{ \delta_{g, \varepsilon}, \delta_{h,\varepsilon} \}$, I affirm that this $\delta_{\varepsilon}$ works, why?, because if $|x-c| < \delta_{\varepsilon}$ then we have two options $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ or not,  if the first happens, that is if $x \in \mathbb{Q}$, then $$|f(x) - L| = |h(x) - L| < \varepsilon$$ and if $x \not\in \mathbb{Q}$, $$|f(x) - L| = |g(x) - L| < \varepsilon $$